# Problem with lattice (just the eyes) and link to the main object

Tags: modifiers, parent

This's my first question here.

The problem:
I have a character (one object), that have the eyes like another object. They're deformed by a lattice and your pupils movement are make by a empty.
[image]

But they're never follow the main object.
[image]

Now i done another thing, i put bones to this eyes and set your weight, everything is fine, but the lattice don't follow nobody and when i move any bone of the character, the lattice stay on their location and deforming the eyes.
I tried to link the lattice to everything and nothing happened.
What i can do?!

Thanks in advance.